# Excel Macro to extract header, and rows then email

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I am attempting to find an Excel macro that would get the headers from a table, and then copy certain rows into an email.

For example

```
State  |  Store  |  Points
Store1 |  VIC    |  3201
Store2 |  NSW    |  1234
Store3 |  QLD    |  4234
```

I have this following code, that allows me to select the whole table, and it copies into the email and sends it, though i need it automated to extract the single rows

```
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function

Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
' Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
     "\Microsoft\Signatures\Default.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email@address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "My Subject here"
        .HTMLBody = "<i></i> Hi<br/>" & _
        "Please find below a summary of activity.<br/><h3>National Summary</h3>" & _
        RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

What I need is for the code to copy rows of a specific Store to the email so only that Store's information is in the message. How can I do this for each unique value in `State` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the HTML file from the sheet's `UsedRange`.

```
'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

After you set `Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name` you could instead declare another range variable to capture ONLY the row(s) needed for each store, and then use that as the `Source:=`.

Your code is not working on my Excel 2010 so I'm not able to verify unfortunately, but instead of using the `usedRange` you **should** be able to just specify a range address in another variable.

Example:

```
Sub PublishObjectFromFilteredRange()
'An example of applying autofilter to sheet
' and setting range variable = to the autofiltered cells/visible cells
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim storeID As String
Dim tableRange As Range
Dim filteredRange As Range
Dim pObj As PublishObject
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'Define the range of the table
Set tableRange = ws.Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown), Range("A1").End(xlToRight))

'Define the Store for which you want to create the report
storeID = "Store 1" '<---- change this as necessary

'Set a filter on the table
tableRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=storeID

'determine the visible table range
Set filteredRange = tableRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Create & publish the PublishObject
Set pObj = ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
    SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\david_zemens\Desktop\publish.htm", _
    sheet:="Sheet1", _
    Source:=filteredRange.Address, _
    HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)

    pObj.Publish True


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David, more or less i need only the header ie State, Store, Points then Store3 only to see the information relating to store 3 does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, makes perfect sense> I just couldn't get your code to work but I have fixed it now. I have revised my answer with a sample of code that uses the AutoFilter. You should be able to modify this to include a loop over the names in column 1, if desired.

Comment: Thanks David I have the code finding the store, and producing the html, how do I get it to feed back to my email. atm im doing this by `On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "address@email"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Monthly Activity Report"
        .HTMLBody = "<i></i> Hi<br/>" & _
        "Please find below a summary of activity.<br/><h3>National Summary</h3>" & _
        PublishObjectFromFilteredRange() & Signature
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as "accepted" and posting your new question as a NEW question.  I would start by trying to play with the code here: http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/email-html-format-message-body-from-excel-vba-2007-4427354